# 3D Modeling Kit - Crash when uploading- Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

Tags: java, android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, 3d-modelling

I'm tring to implement the [3D Modeling](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-3d-modeling) SDK and it keeps crashing when I upload the photos to build the model.

When the crash happended, the following log is displayed:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1333)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:916)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:458)
    at com.huawei.hms.materialgeneratesdk.t.b.a(AbstractRestClientProvider.java:8)
    at com.huawei.hms.materialgeneratesdk.t.f.a(RestClientManager.java:11)
    at com.huawei.hms.materialgeneratesdk.t.B.a(RemoteClient.java:41)
    at com.huawei.hms.materialgeneratesdk.t.K.a(GetTaskIdWork.java:5)
    at com.huawei.hms.materialgeneratesdk.cloud.Modeling3dTextureEngine.initTask(Modeling3dTextureEngine.java:6)
    at com.huawei.hms.modeling3d.ui.modelingui.CaptureMaterialActivity$2.run(CaptureMaterialActivity.java:210)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

What I have done:

1. Downloaded the demo project from GitHub
2. Create my own App on AGC and replace the agconnect-services.json file in the project
3. Replace the applicationId in the build.gradle file to the package name of my App
4. Initialize the ReconstructApplication and MaterialGenApplication using api_key from my App

When this crash happens:
Finish taking photos and click the "Upload" button, I also tried restarting the app or uploading the photos manually, but the error is the same.

Could anyone give any clue? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the **default data processing location** of the project on the APPGallery Connect website.

[image]

For more details, see the [3D Modeling development guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/graphics-Guides/config-agc-0000001142925473).